# Django: view formatted sql in console

Tags: sql, django, logging

I want to see formated sql queries in the console of Django while developing

I have tried adding the below code to settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', ],
        },
    },
}
```

Now whenever there is any sql query it shows in the django console.

But its not well formatted. So how can i see the formatted sql queries instead of single line

Comment: give example how you getting in single line

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer at this link [Syntax highlighting for Django’s SQL query logging](https://markusholtermann.eu/2016/01/syntax-highlighting-for-djangos-sql-query-logging/)

I just added the following to my settings.py and now the sql is formatted in console even in jupyter notebook

```
import logging

class SQLFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):

        # Check if Pygments is available for coloring
        try:
            import pygments
            from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
            from pygments.formatters import TerminalTrueColorFormatter
        except ImportError:
            pygments = None

        # Check if sqlparse is available for indentation
        try:
            import sqlparse
        except ImportError:
            sqlparse = None

        # Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
        sql = record.sql.strip()

        if sqlparse:
            # Indent the SQL query
            sql = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True)

        if pygments:
            # Highlight the SQL query
            sql = pygments.highlight(
                sql,
                SqlLexer(),
                #TerminalTrueColorFormatter(style='monokai')
                TerminalTrueColorFormatter()
            )

        # Set the records statement to the formatted query
        record.statement = sql
        return super(SQLFormatter, self).format(record)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'sql': {
            '()': SQLFormatter,
            'format': '[%(duration).3f] %(statement)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'sql': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'sql',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['sql'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.db.backends.schema': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```